# Pass $(this) as argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function GetDeals() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
}

$('.filterResult').live("click", function(event) {
    GetDeals();
});
```

});

What do I need to pass as argument in function `GetDeals()` so that I can manipulate with `$(this)`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could just use the function as your event handle:

```
$('.filterResult').live("click", GetDeals);
```

(please note, you don't use the `()` to call the function, so the function itself is being passed to the `live()` function, not its result.

Or you can use [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply)

```
$('.filterResult').live("click", function(event) {
  GetDeals.apply(this);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Above solution works and absolutely no issues with that. However I believe a better pattern here is :

```
$('.filterResult').live("click", function(event) {
    GetDeals($(this));
});


function GetDeals(linkObj) {
    var id = $(linkObj).attr("id");
    console.log(id);
}
```